# sharepoint modal popup to display div content

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to show a div content in a sharepoint modal popup. Below is my code:

```
function callPopup(){
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.html = addFilePopup //id of the div to be displayed
    options.title = 'Add file';
    options.width = 300;
    options.height = 150;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="addFilePopup" align="center" runat="server">
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <div id="divOverwrite" style="margin-right: 60px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkOverWrite" value="overwrite" />
            <label id="lblOverwrite">Overwrite if file already exists</label>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <input type="button" value="Add file" id="btnAddFile" onclick="AddAFile();"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" />
        </div>
</div>
```

The popup shows itself fine for the first time.
But if the function callPopup is called for the second time, it says "addFilePopup" is undefined. 
It seems that the div "addFilePopup" is removed from the DOM after the popup is called for the first time. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

P.S: I have tried with and without "runat=server" for the div.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you clone that should be yout very last resort,as it brings a lot of side effects with in - e.g. doubled ids.

I assume callPopup() is an event callback.  Let's say your click event on a button opens this popup which in turns should visualize html code, which has already been loaded to the DOM.

```
   $('#addFilePopup').hide();

   function callPopup(){
      var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
      options.html = addFilePopup //id of the div to be displayed
      options.title = 'Add file';
      options.width = 300;
      options.height = 150;
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
   }
```

This should keep your html hidden and the same time loaded into the DOM.
When the event is triggered, you should add

```
 $('#addFilePopup').show();
```

Your code should look something like that:

```
$('#addFilePopup').hide();
function callPopup(){
$('#addFilePopup').show();
  var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
  options.html = addFilePopup //id of the div to be displayed
  options.title = 'Add file';
  options.width = 300;
  options.height = 150;
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

}

Since options.html has to receive DOM element,contrary to what msdn documentation states, This is the most simple way I know. I can't argue if it's ideal but depending on application complexity it might give a hint of valid options in terms of Sharepoint Popups.

P.S. I know it's 6 years later, but if someone comes accross this issue, hopefully will provide event better solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a sharepoint newbie but I this happened to me before. What happens is that you are using the original div and it does get removed after your first calling. If you are still having this problem you can use the jQuery clone() function.

So instead of 
`options.html = addFilePopUp`

I'd suggest making a variable for your div first

```
var popUpDiv = $("div#addFilePopUp").clone();
```

and then calling your options

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.html = popUpDiv;
options.title = 'Add file';
options.width = 300;
options.height = 150;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

This will create multiple instances of your div though so you'll have to hide the original using css. Hope this helps.